# how to avoid ckeditor to replace &lt to real tag

Tags: ckeditor

Using CKEDITOR3, i need to be able to enter:

```
<p>dummy</p>: This tag is really good at stuff....
```

Note that the brackets should show, as it's for documenting tags.

As i enter the brackets in the texteditor-area they're saved in db as &lt; etc and retrieved back to the *source of the textarea* as &lt; but then the CKEDITOR htmlWriter probably kicks in and strips &lt to a bracket and that's what shows in the editor.

Can I prevent this behaviour in CKEditor. If I would enter real tags, I use the CKEDITOR-source view. Now i really want to have the tags printed and thus keep the &lt; .

**Note:**

```
If I enter &amp;lt;test&amp;gt; and submits the code, 
the editor first changes to &lt;test&gt; and then submitted once more,
to <test>.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in case anyone else stumbles:

Simply pass the data trough

```
(php): $ckHtml = htmlspecialchars($theText)
```

before presenting the body-data to the CK-editor area.